# Create a shapefile of concentric circles in Python by buffering a point at different levels

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, pandas

The following code returns only the last circle's geometry. I need a shapefile containing geometry of all buffer operations.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
import numpy as np
d = pd.DataFrame({'x': [50], 'y': [50]})
gdf = (gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(d.x, d.y)))
for i in range(1, 10,1):
    gdf[ 'geometry' ] = gdf.geometry.buffer(i)
    gdf.geometry.append(gdf.geometry)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a column with lists of buffered geometries and explode:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
d = pd.DataFrame({'x': [572311], 'y': [6450763 ]})
gdf = (gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(d.x, d.y)))
gdf.crs = 3006

def bufferthem(row):
    return [row.geometry.buffer(x) for x in range(5000, 10000, 2000)]

gdf['buffers'] = gdf.apply(lambda x: bufferthem(x), axis=1) #Create a column with a list of buffered geometries

gdf = gdf.explode('buffers') #Explode to create a new row for each list element
gdf = gdf.set_geometry('buffers') #Set the geometry to the buffer column
del(gdf['geometry'])

gdf.to_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest copy/buffered.shp')
```

[image]

If explode doesnt work:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [572311, 571046], 'y': [6450763, 6451663]})
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.x, df.y), crs="epsg:3006")

buffers = [[g.buffer(x) for x in  range(5000, 10000, 2000)] for g in gdf['geometry']] #Just another way of buffering without a function and apply
buffers = [buffer for bufferlist in buffers for buffer in bufferlist] #List of lists into one list (flattening)

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(buffers)/df.shape[1])] #duplicate each row three times, to match the number of buffers
df['geometry'] = buffers

gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry', crs="epsg:3006")
gdf2.to_file(r'C:\GIS\data\tempdata\buffers_exploded.shp')
```

Comment: Thank you very much @BERA! I got the following error for gdf.explode('buffers') function: TypeError: explode() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.

Comment: :) I get the same error when I try it on another computer, weird. I've added another way without explode